# caseId property is not shown in response received from a external service to Salesforce

Tags: json, callout, httprequest, httpresponse, httppost

I am making a POST callout from salesforce to another service and case is one of the objects of JSON which i am sending (see below)

```
"case": {
   "caseId": "00000212",
   "status":"",
   "statusReason":""
}
```

Same is sent in response with updated "status" and "statusReason" values. Since CASE cannot be used as a property for JSONtoApex class i am replacing it with "caseObj". So the response should be

```
"caseObj": {
       "caseId": "00000212",
       "status":"",
       "statusReason":""
    }
```

For some reason i am seeing only "status" and "statusReason" but not the "caseId" in the response. It is working fine when i call the same service with same payload through POSTMAN, i am able to see the "caseId". Looks like the problem is within salesforce, i also tried replacing "caseId" with some other property but still didn't work.

**Response in Salesforce (highlighted in red):**
[image]

**Response in POSTMAN**

[image]

**UPDATED SECTION**

**CalloutHelper**

```
public class CalloutHelper{
  public static String postData(String body){
    HttpRequest rq = new HttpRequest();
    rq.setEndpoint('myendpoint');
    rq.setMethod('POST');
    rq.setbody(body);

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse rs = http.send(rq);
    if(rs.getStatusCode() == 200){
     return rs.getBody();
    } else {
     return 'That did not work';  
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

**JSONResponseClass**

```
public class JSONResponseClass {

  public responseBody{
    @AuraEnabled
    public String correspondenceId;
    @AuraEnabled
    public cls_recipients[] recipients;
  }

  public class cls_recipients {
    @AuraEnabled
    public cls_case caseObj;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String firstName;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String lastName;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String email;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String fax;
    @AuraEnabled
    public cls_address address;
  }

  public class cls_case {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String caseId;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String status;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String statusReason;
  }

public class cls_address {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String street;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String city;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String state;
  }

  public static responseBody sendData(String body){
    String returnValue = calloutHelper.postData(body);
    returnValue = returnvalue.replace('case','caseObj');
    return (responseBody) System.JSON.deserialize(returnValue, responseBody.class);
  }
}
```

I am calling JSONResponseClass in a lightning component and sending "body" as a param to Apex controller. From the images above, first image is what the response received captured through chrome (console tab) using *JSON.stringify(response)*.

**Response Body Before Serialization**

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using any apex wrapper?

Comment: Please update your question to include the actual code you are using including an object wrappers, deserialization methods and how you are generating the output that you have shown us when.

Comment: @gNerb Apologies for not providing the code. Please see the updated section of the question.

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni yes

Comment: provided JSON.stringify(response).is before serialization? Are you getting caseId before serialization?

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni you raised a good point. JSON.stringify(response) is after serialization and i am getting caseId before serialization.. i guess something's wrong with the wrapper class?

Comment: Show your response which received before serialization

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni posted picture in the question at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace response body before serialization like below. It will change case object to caseObj which you have refereed in class.

```
jsonString.replace('"case":', '"caseObj":');
```

After this you can de-serialize and it will work.

Comment: I did that.. i have not included here in the code. Please see the Response In Salesforce image in the question. you will see "caseObj" instead of "case"

Comment: returnValue = returnvalue.replace('case','caseObj'); looks like case in caseId is also replacing with caseObj so it is not de-serializing. use code which i have added in answer to replace.

Comment: Ah!! i completely forgot that "caseId" also has "case" in it and that is being replaced with caseObj. Thanks, that worked!